# Find end of coffeescript function

Tags: javascript, function, coffeescript

How do I trigger a function at the end of another function in coffeescript? If I have these functions in coffeescript:

```
textAnim = true
buttonAnim = false

textAnim = (    
    // do stuff
    textAnim = false
    buttonAnim = true
)

textAnim.on 'end', ->
    buttonAnim = true

buttonAnim = (
    // do stuff
)
```

textAnim works fine. How do I trigger  `buttonAnim`? Thanks for any ideas!

---

EDIT

```
textAnim = (    
    // do stuff
    buttonAnim()
)

buttonAnim = (
    // do stuff
)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to call a function from another function? just call `buttonAnim()` within that function. Don't forget the brackets!

Comment: Okay thanks @benjaminjosephw! Changed it to the above, but got an error sadly `TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a function (evaluating 'buttonAnim()')` Perhaps I misunderstood you.. Thanks for your input!

Comment: currently you're defining objects, not functions. See the coffeescript docs for more info: http://coffeescript.org/#literals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to define these functions in coffeescript would be like this:

```
textAnim = ->    
    # do stuff
    buttonAnim()

buttonAnim = ->
    # do stuff
```